# È corretto "...cui ambisca ad essere come"?

Tags: word-choice, word-order

È corretta la frase seguente?

> Credo, alla fin fine, Dante Alighieri sia l'unica persona cui ambisca — senza esito — ad essere come.

Ciò che mi lascia perplesso è quel 'cui ambisca ad essere come'; frammento che, più comunemente, molti riscriverebbero 'a cui vorrei essere uguale', eventualmente anche senza 'a' prima di 'cui'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Terminare una relativa con una proposizione è una costruzione abbastanza comune in inglese, ma in italiano non si usa proprio. Le proposizioni vanno attaccate al pronome relativo:

> This is the road (**that**) I arrived **from** / This is the road **from which** I arrived.
>
> Questa è la strada **da cui** sono venuto / Questa è la strada **dalla quale** sono venuto.

Tra l'altro, la frase citata dice *credo Dante Alighieri sia*, non *credo **che** Dante Alighieri sia*: omettere quel *che* è molto comune in inglese, ma anche questa abbastanza sconosciuta in italiano. È un altro indizio che fa pensare che sia una frase tradotta troppo letteralmente.

C'è però un altra questione più importante: in inglese *like* è in tutto e per tutto una preposizione, come confermano [diversi](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/like) [vocabolari](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/like), ma in italiano è un avverbio che introduce un complemento; più ci penso e più mi sembra un oggetto abbastanza strano. In particolare mi sembra che non si possa usare per introdurre una relativa: tecnicamente immagino che si debba costruire così

> *Credo, alla fin fine, **che** Dante Alighieri sia l'unica persona *come la quale* ambisca — senza esito — ad essere.

(o forse *ambisco*, che mi suona meglio). Una relativa con "come la quale", o "come cui", però non l'ho mai sentita, appunto perché *come* non è una proposizione. Insomma, direi che è una costruzione che in italiano non esiste. L'unica soluzione è riformulare la frase.

Answer (score 6):

No, in italiano non direi così, mi sembra quasi una traduzione fatta con un traduttore automatico.

Si potrebbe dire:

> Credo che Dante Alighieri sia l'unica persona a cui vorrei assomigliare, ma senza successo.

Volendo usare il verbo "ambire" (anche se mi sembra molto formale):

> Credo che la sola persona a cui ambisca assomigliare, ma senza successo, sia Dante Alighieri.

"Alla fin fine" è più da linguaggio parlato e stona un po' con un "ambire" che non è certo da linguaggio parlato.

Answer (score 1):

È inusuale, e stona all'orecchio, ma non la riterrei di per sé grammaticalmente sbagliata.

Se rimpiazzi "essere come" con l'equivalente "assomigliare" suona benissimo:

"Credo, alla fin fine, Dante Alighieri sia l'unica persona cui ambisca — senza esito — ad assomigliare."

Comment: ...con la differenza che “assomigliare” si costruisce con il “dativo” (assomigliare **a** qualcuno), “essere come” no. Così com'è, quella frase dice che il parlante vuole essere “come a Dante Alighieri”.

Comment: @DaG potresti avere ragione, ma non sono del tutto convinto :/ Sfortunatamente ngram non pare ritornare risultati nemmeno per "ambire a[d] essere", che e' sicuramente corretto.

Comment: Che c'entra Ngram? Tu dici “voglio essere come a Dante”?

Comment: @DaG cercavo esempi della forma "ambire ad essere" per vedere se ne esistevano con "come", ma non essendoci ne' con ne' senza non posso tirare conclusioni basate su quello. Tutto qui :)

Comment: Ma Ngram non è un'autorità: è un corpus neppure troppo affidabile di libri scanditi da Google. Visto che il verbo “ambire” si costruisce con “a”, puoi dire “ambire a essere”, “ambire a fare una capriola”, “ambire a diventare re di Norvegia” anche se nessuno l'ha mai detto prima. È questo il bello delle lingue.